# How can I write this SQL SELECT query?

Tags: sql

Say I have two tables. new_dogs and name_color_pairs.

The records in name_color_pairs must be unique pairs.

```
new_dogs
---------
Name
Location Found
Color
Breed


name_color_pairs
---------
name
color
```

How can I select the name/color pairs from new_dogs that aren't currently in the name_color_pairs table so that they can be inserted?

Comment: You should write database, that you are using. Is it MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT name, color FROM new_dogs
EXCEPT
SELECT name, color FROM name_color_pairs
```

or

```
SELECT name, color FROM new_dogs nd
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT name, color FROM name_color_pairs ncp WHERE (ncp.name = nd.name) AND (ncp.color = nd.color))
```

or finally (should be working everywhere):

```
SELECT name, color FROM new_dogs nd
LEFT JOIN name_color_pairs ncp
ON (ncp.color = nd.color) AND (ncp.name = nd.name)
WHERE ncp.name IS NULL
```

Comment: any chance you know how to solve this related question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942650/how-would-i-write-this-sql-update-query