# How would I write this SQL UPDATE query?

Tags: sql, database

Say I have two tables:

```
new_dogs   <<---- CONTAINS DOGS SPOTTED TODAY
---------
name
breed
color
location
found_date

dog_locations  <<---- CONTAINS A HISTORY OF ALL DOGS EVER SPOTTED
---------------
name
breed
location
from_date
thru_date
```

The new_dogs table is populated with dogs found today. Say I found a white poodle named max at the park 3 days in a row. On the first day, max is inserted into the dog_locations table at the park with a from_date of found_date.

2nd day max shows up as still at the park so nothing needs to be done

3rd day max is no longer in the new_dogs table(which could be called the dogs_found_today table) meaning he is no longer at the park.  This means that his entry in dog_locations is no longer valid, so i want to close his thru_date.

What I need to do is update the thru_date on dogs that exist in the dog_locations table, but do not exist in the new_dogs table and have a thru_date of NULL. The thru_date will be set to CURRENT_DATE()

Each dog_location must be unique with the primary key being (name;breed;location;from_date)

I do not know how to go about this one.

I am able to select dogs that are in dog_locations but not in new_dogs like this:

```
SELECT name, breed, location, from_date
FROM dog_locations dl
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT name, breed, location, found_date
              FROM new_dogs nd
              WHERE (nd.name = dl.name) AND (nd.breed = dl.breed)
                                    AND (nd.location = dl.location) 
                                    AND (nd.found_date = dl.from_date));
```

Comment: I was able to select all the dogs that were in dog_locations and not in new_dogs, but I couldn't hook up an Update to it.

Comment: Please clarify something: you said to update dogs that do not occur in the new_dogs table but then said to use the new_dogs.found_date as the new thru_date. If no record exists for that dog how can we use that found date?

Comment: @davidethell I have updated the question to say that it should be set to CURRENT_DATE()

Comment: What are the primary keys of the two tables?

Comment: @HillBilly.Developer the Primary Key of dog_locations is a composite key consisting of name, breed, location, from_date. new_dogs does not have a primary key (it is basically a temporary table)

Comment: Is `found_date` in `new_dogs` equivalent to `from_date` in `dog_locations`?

Comment: @HillBilly.Developer found_date is used when inserting new dog_locations as the from_date yes

Comment: If they "don't exist in the new dogs table", then you can't "Update" them, you have to create that record first... so your question is probably not stated correctly

Comment: @Charles - he needs to update `dog_locations.thru_date = CURRENT_DATE()` where the dog doesn't exist in `new_dogs`

Comment: @MikeJerome let's see your select statement

Comment: @Charles I have updated my question to hopefully clarify

Comment: @HillBilly.Developer I have added the select statement to the question.

Comment: You are having SQL problems, because your database design is just poor. Dogs should not be identified by name/breed pair, you probably should have a table called dogs. Primary keys should not be related to data, just identity types. Proper database design solves a lot of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE dog_locations SET thru_date = <actualdate or whichever date> 
FROM dog_locations dl
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT name, breed, location, found_date
              FROM new_dogs nd
              WHERE (nd.name = dl.name) AND (nd.breed = dl.breed)
                                    AND (nd.location = dl.location) 
                                    AND (nd.found_date = dl.from_date));
```

Cheers
Anja

But you should really rethink your database design and follow LukLeds idea introducing a table dogs...